# New line with yacc generated parser is ignored

Tags: c, yacc

This interpreter on ubuntu 20.04 has problem with new lines.

s1.l

```
%%
(a|b)*  { strcpy(yylval.string, yytext);
      return AB; 
        }
z   return Z;
'\n'    return yytext[0];
.   return yytext[0];
%%
```

s1.y

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define check(first, two) \
        if (strcmp(first, two)) \
            fprintf(stderr, " -------- no word of language S1\n"); \
        else \
            fprintf(stderr, " --------  word of language S1\n");
int yylex();
void yyerror();

%}
%union {
    char string[100];
}
%token Z
%token <string> AB

%%
word: AB Z AB '\n' { check($1, $3); }  
    | word AB Z AB '\n' { check($2, $4); } 
    | error '\n'
    ;
%%
#include "lex.yy.c"
void yyerror(char *s)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "no word of language S1\n"); 
}
```

When I am running the interpreter the new line character is not recognized.

```
./s1
aazbb
```

Comment: How do you know `\n` is not recognised? Is it giving you some error message? If so, you should include that in your question.

Answer (score 3):

lex does not treat `'` as a special character (denoting a single character), so when you have a pattern `'\n'` it matches that literal 3-character sequence.  Use `"\n"` (or just `\n`) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Your pattern is a new line surrounded by simple quotes, then lex (or flex) is expecting that to return a new line to the parser and it is normal that the new line is not recognized. You should simply remove the simple quotes as follows:

```
%%
(a|b)*  { strcpy(yylval.string, yytext);
      return AB; 
        }
z   return Z;
\n    return yytext[0];
.   return yytext[0];
%%
```

Comment: `.|\n return yytext[0];` "Then lex (or flex) is expecting that to return a new line to the parser": this is the *problem* because it isn't true.